# Gzip compression exception in symbian c++

Tags: c++, symbian

```
Compress(TInt aCompressionMethod,const TDesC8 data)
{
  TInt compressionMethod = 0;
  if(aCompressionMethod == 0)
    compressionMethod = Z_DEFAULT_COMPRESSION;

  iCompressor =CEZCompressor::NewLC(*this,Z_DEFAULT_COMPRESSION);

  TRAPD(err, iCompressor->CompressL(cipher,text));
}
```

I am using compression using `gzip` method in symbian in client side and on server side server is in Java.

The problem is that on server side in Java `gZip` format is not matched exception is thrown.

I want to know the method I am using to compress string is correct or wrong, or whether I have to made change or server side has to change.

Comment: You need to add your implementation of MEZBufferManager to your question, so we can figure out whether in contains a problem. We also need to know where the cipher variable comes from and what you do with it before you send it to the server.

Comment: hi,
thanks for response i am not using MEZBufferManager b'coz i want to compress string not file into gzip format
and on server side they are using decompress string in java

Answer (score 0):

`CEZCompressor` will just give you the deflate-compressed data. It does not contain any gzip-specific header information. If your server-side java implementation needs to see that information, use the `CEZGZipToFile` class.

There's a nice example at [Forum Nokia wiki](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/CS000949_-_Compressing_and_decompressing_GZIP_files).

Hope this helps. If not, please add details to your question. Currently it is a little bit on the vague side.

Comment: hi,

i am using this class to compress string and on server i have to decompress that string not string

would u plz suggest correct way to compress string not file